# Disable and Grey out Section when button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, disabled-input

I am in the middle of creating a form and I would like to have certain sections greyed out and disabled until the person answers Yes for each section.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#submit').prop('disabled', true); // disabled by default

$('#checkbox').click(function() {
   // change on checkbox click
   $('#submit').prop('disabled', !$('#checkbox').prop('checked'));
});
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/artboycat/p7g9h2p2/1/

Answer (score 0):

put this div in the fieldset(of your example):

```
    <div style="position:absolute;width:90%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.5)">
</div>
```